# Getting option element based on custom attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following:

```
<select id="selector">
<option data-origin-table="foo1" data-origin-col="bar1">
<option data-origin-table="foo2" data-origin-col="bar2">
<option data-origin-table="foo3" data-origin-col="bar3">
...
</select>
```

I am trying to select an `option` based on the custom attributes but I am having no success.

I tried the following ways but they all failed.

```
console.log($('#selector option').filter(function () { return $(this)[0].getAttribute('data-origin-table') == "foo2" && $(this)[0].getAttribute('data-origin-col')=="bar2"; }).val());

console.log($('#selector option').filter(function () { return $(this).getAttribute('data-origin-table') == "foo2" && $(this).getAttribute('data-origin-col')=="bar2"; }).val());

console.log($('#selector option').filter(function () { return $(this).attr('data-origin-table') == "foo2" && $(this).attr('data-origin-col')=="bar2"; }).val());
```

Any clues on how to properly do this?

Using `jquery 2.2.3` if it helps.
Thanks!

Comment: You ask for the `.val()` but none of your options have a `value` attribute

Comment: you can do `$('#selector option[data-origin-table=foo1]');`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use an attribute selector:

```js
var val = $('#selector option[data-origin-table="foo2"][data-origin-col="bar2"]').val();
console.log(val);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector">
  <option data-origin-table="foo1" data-origin-col="bar1" value="foo">A</option>
  <option data-origin-table="foo2" data-origin-col="bar2" value="bar">B</option>
  <option data-origin-table="foo3" data-origin-col="bar3" value="fizz">C</option>
</select>
```

Or you could use `filter()`:

```js
var val = $('#selector option').filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('origin-table') === 'foo2' && $(this).data('origin-col') === 'bar2';
}).val();
console.log(val);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector">
  <option data-origin-table="foo1" data-origin-col="bar1" value="foo">A</option>
  <option data-origin-table="foo2" data-origin-col="bar2" value="bar">B</option>
  <option data-origin-table="foo3" data-origin-col="bar3" value="fizz">C</option>
</select>
```